# Card action label (optional)

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

In our Garden environment, we cleared the value in the **Card action label (optional)** setting, refreshed the screen, and the **View More** button no longer appears on the card (this is the expected behavior).

In the production environment, for a mutual client, we cleared the value in the **Card action label (optional)** setting, refreshed, and a button appears with a label that we did not define (appears to be a hardcoded default).

In reviewing the [documentation](https://knowledge.banno.com/people/settings/plugin-card-configuration/), it indicates that the *Dashboard Configuration* should include the following settings:

- **Card action (optional)**
- **Label (optional)**

However, in the production environment, there is only a **Card action label (optional)** setting. This is also the only setting that we can define in the Garden environment.

What do we need to do in the production environment, in addition to clearing the **Card action label (optional)** setting, so that a button does not appear on our card? [Plugin Configuration Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YW8p.png)

Answer (score 1):

## The short answer

The short answer is that you would need the Banno Admin at the financial institution to 'clear out the selection' of the External Application for the *Card action (optional)* section in Banno People.

That will remove the primary action button from the plugin card.

## The long answer

The long answer is that there is some confusion based on some differences between how plugins are configured by the Banno Admin at a financial institution compared to how plugins are configured via a developer account on JackHenry.Dev.

The [Banno Admin at a financial institution can configure a plugin](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/configuration/) to use up to *two* External Applications. The first External Application is used for the *Card Face*. The second External Application, configured via the *Card action (optional)* section, is used for the primary action button that activates the *Expanded View*. This gives some flexibility in that the two selections can be *different* External Applications or can be the *same* External Application (selected twice). The best way to remove the primary action button is to clear out both items in the *Card action (optional)* section:

1. *Label (optional)*
2. *External application* (which would be the 'Choose an integration' option in the dropdown list)

In contrast, when using the [self-serve options via a developer account on JackHenry.Dev](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/accessing-the-digital-toolkit/), the options for configuring a plugin are more limited. For developer accounts, we currently only support:

1. a plugin card *without* a primary action button
2. a plugin card *with* a primary action button (the same External Application used for both the *Card Face* and *Expanded View*, and clearing the *Card action label (optional)* text will remove the button)

I hope this helps explain the options.

Comment: Jamie, thanks, now I get it.   That 2nd Exernal Application we see is for the "View more"  launch option which 1) can match the 1st External App, 2) be a differrent External App (most likely to present a differnt view than the embedded, and 3) we can "clear" that 2nd App and the label to remove the "view more" button.

In our case we will clear it to remove the "View more" launch option.

Comment: Correct, that's how it works. You've got it.